# Error installing Ubuntu Server 16.04 on VMWare

Tags: server, 16.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on VMware Workstation 11 but facing an error :

```
Network boot from Intel E1000
Copyright (C) 2003-2014 VMware, Inc
Copyright (C) 1997-2000 Intel Corporation

....
PXE-E53: No boot filename received

PXE-MOF: Exiting Intel PXE ROM
Operating System not found
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

Your Virtual Machine is trying to boot from [PXE](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) (this is a network boot protocol). Unless you have a network boot server on your local LAN, it will not work.

You need to configure VMWare to boot from removable media, and "insert" the Ubuntu image (.iso) in a virtual drive.

Go to the VM Settings > Hardware and, if not present, add a CD/DVD drive. Then connect the Ubuntu ISO to it and boot your Virtual Machine again.

Link to [VMWare WS 11 documentation for adding CD drives](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-F71E5A37-AB32-41A9-AAC3-D87F25F5279F.html).

Comment: It's still not solving the problem. I try to disable network boot (with this `ethernet0.opromsize = "true"` in config file) in vain https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014906

Comment: You should be able to select the boot device from the BIOS or Boot Menu (F2), to ensure you boot from the DVD drive. Check https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004129 for more information.